# Facebook login without using facebook login button on Android with native dialog

Tags: android, facebook

In my application, I have a requirement to login to facebook without using login button. I have tried following code snippet

```
    Session s = new Session(activity);
    Session.setActiveSession(s);
    Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
    request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
    request.setCallback( new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Facebook" + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                closeTask = true;
            }
            else if(session.getState().isOpened()){}
        }
    });
```

But it is opening web dialog. My requirement is to open native dialog if facebook app is installed. If facebook app is not installed then open web dialog.

Thanks,
Manish Garg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this line:

```
request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

It tells the SDK to suppress SSO (which is the native dialog).

Comment: Hi Ming, I have used SUPRESS_SSO, because I am also doing facebook loogout using Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();. After logout when I again try to login without using SUPRESS_SSO, application is not asking for the user credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by "not asking for user credentials"? Does it just give you an access token?

Comment: Let say user performs following actions: 1. Facebook application is not logged in and User login first time through the application, it also logged in the facebook application (behaves like single sign on). 2. User logout facebook using my application, closeAndClearTokenInformation closes session only for the application. 3. User again try to login using my application to the facebook, as facebook application is already logged in, only application session is closed, facebook api doesn't ask asking for the user credentials and open the session.

Comment: That's expected behavior. If the user has already logged in via your app, you will just get an access token from the FB app without any further user interaction. It's only when you ask for additional permissions that any additional UI is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Ming, I have removed this line and its working. Now I am searching some other solution for logout functionality